# USB user Space device driver for a custom device

Tags: linux, usb, device, linux-device-driver, drivers

What is a "USB user Space device driver for a custom device?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A *user-space device driver* is a piece of software (a library or a daemon) that is used to get access to a custom device (a gadget). The difference with a kernel driver is that the user-space driver is run from the normal user-space, not from the kernel. That is, it is compiled and run as normal code just as any other program/library.

In order to do this, you need to access the low-level USB features from your program, but the Linux kernel gently provides that. Anyway, do not try to talk to the kernel directly, that is madness. Instead use a USB library, such as [libusb](http://libusb.info/)

Comment: @sagarreddy: No, sorry, no simple samples. But you can find a few examples in the libuxbx site.

Comment: libusbx was merged to libusb in 2014, and as a separate project, it has been discontinued.